# PyEZ RPC options format differ between get_configuration and other calls

Tags: python

When using RPC calls in PyEZ we add the parameters as named arguments like `rpc.get_interface_information(terse="True", interface-name="xe-0/0/0")`, however for configuration the options need to be within a dictionary like `rpc.get_configuration({"inherit":"inherit", "groups":"groups"})`

What's the reason for these differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to describe it is this:
With non-configuration rpcs, each of the items is it's own element and in PyEZ we use the parameters to determine that we are referencing elements.

```
<get-interface-information>
        <routing-instance>routing-instance</routing-instance>
        <extensive/>
        <statistics/>
        <media/>
        <detail/>
        <terse/>
        <brief/>
        <descriptions/>
        <snmp-index>snmp-index</snmp-index>
        <switch-port>switch-port</switch-port>
        <interface-name>interface-name</interface-name>

</get-interface-information>
```

In the case of the get-configuration rpc, all of the items you are referencing are actually attributes of the get-configuration tag itself, not elements defined in the rpc.

```
 <get-configuration 
                        [changed="changed"] 
                        [commit-scripts="( apply | apply-no-transients | view )"]
                        [compare="rollback" [rollback="[0-49]"]]
                        [database="(candidate | committed)"]
                        [database-path=$junos-context/commit-context/database-path]
                        [format="( text | xml )"]
                        [inherit="( defaults | inherit )"
                                   [groups="groups"] [interface-ranges="interface-ranges"]]
                        [(junos:key | key )="key"] >

    <!-- tag elements for the configuration element to display -->
</get-configuration>
```

So, to know whether an rpc (which we create dynamically in PyEZ) is referencing an element or an attribute is the usage of parameters or a dictionary, respectively.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Edward, what's the best way to see those tags / check whether something is an attribute instead of an element?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Edward's answer, I believe the PyEZ RPC calls are implemented using reflection (`__call__` method), so today it is not aware of valid RPC calls nor args. The way to make it aware would be to load the Netconf schema dynamically from the device and use that to map the named arg to a tag or an element.
A potential issue from trying to abstract this calling convention from the user is what to do when there is a tag and an element with the same name for the same RPC – not sure if that is the case today or there are rules to prevent this in the schemas, but in that case the user of the call should be able to control what goes in the RPC doc IMHO.